# Why not past tense?

Tags: present-tense, historical-present

In this [transcript](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=332581061) it tells a story:

> There's a story probably heard before: a brother and sister are abandoned in the woods by the parents. Soon they meet a witch, who locks the little boy in a shed and begins to fatten him up, planning to eat him.

Why it is not in past tense? Can we tell a story in present tense?

Comment: It's perfectly OK to use the present tense. I've found this article at Wikipedia concerning its use in narratives: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present

Comment: If your story seems modern, current tense is better. But if your story seems historical, use past tense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Present-tense narrative is common in jokes (*A priest, a minister, and a rabbi **walk** into a bar...*) and in some folktale traditions, and it has become something of a mannerism in some contemporary novels. In this case, however, the present tense is employed because the speaker is not actually telling the story but **re**-telling it and summarizing its key events. As I wrote in [another context here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14022/32)

> The convention in English for at least five hundred years has been that when you are describing an existing story/novel/drama/opera you employ the present tense, as if the story were unfolding before your eyes.

Plot summaries in programs and critical works are almost always cast in the 'historical present'.